# Limit entries for each category

Tags: categories, templates

I have this tag which pulls entries from all categories:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="foto" category="1|2|3" limit="15" }
   //content
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Is it possible to pull 15 entries per category? So it would result in 45 entries in total?

I want to shuffle it afterwards therfore I don't want to call this tag three times.

Comment: ... What happens when you put a limit of 45? Does it evenly pull 15 per category?

Comment: It just pulls 45 entries from the first categories since there are more than 15 entries per category. If there would be 10 entries in the first category it would pull 10 from the first and 35 from the second category.

Comment: Also, if you are going to shuffle it **after** (I assume jQuery), why does it matter if you call it three times in a series?

Comment: I'd prefer to use `orderby="random"`.

Comment: As for the `limit="45"` path, if you put your three categories in a category_group, does that give better results (output even amounts from each category?) I can't imagine it will, but it's worth a shot....

Comment: category_group did the trick: `{exp:channel:entries channel="foto" category_group="1" limit="45" orderby="random" }
      //bla
     {/exp:channel:entries}` would you mind wirting it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a category group with your three categories, you can set the `category_group` param on your entries loop. This will pull a rounded, even amount of entries from each category in the group. In an example where you have three categories in `category_group` 1:

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="catburgers"
    category_group="1"
    limit="9"
    orderby="random"}

    {!-- This will output, in random order, 9 entries from the category group, 3 from each category --}

    {title} - Catburger

{/exp:channel:entries}
```